# Trying to setup Xcode with OpenGL

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl, glfw

I've been trying to setup Xcode with OpenGL, but I can't get it to work.

I have been getting this error every time:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/parisjackson-newman/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/GLFW_OpenGL-fjibdenxheioomgsseembfpbmeih/Build/Products/Debug/GLFW OpenGL
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/opt/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/opt/glfw/lib/libglfw.3.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
    /usr/local/lib/libglfw.3.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/lib/libglfw.3.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
    /usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.2/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib: code signature in (/usr/local/Cellar/glfw/3.3.2/lib/libglfw.3.3.dylib) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
(lldb)
```

I used home-brew to install glfw and glew. And the code I am running is [the standard window code from the glfw.org website](https://www.glfw.org/documentation.html)

Answer (score 3):

Go to your *Project Navigator* and select your project.

Then, go to the *Hardened Runtime* section under the *Signing & Capabilities* tab.

Click the checkbox for *Disable Library Validation*.

Once this is done, you should be able to run your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems root issue

1. install glfw from a package manager like brew `brew install glfw`
2. xcode search headers path `usr/local/include`
3. xcode search libraries path `usr/local/lib`